# Django Admin register ManyToMany intermediate model

Tags: python, django

I create the following models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    some_var = models.CharField()

class Parent(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
```

Django automatically creates an intermediary model in the background called `ParentChild`. Now, I would like to register that intermediary model in the Django Admin. Is that possible? If so, how? Or does it only work with `through="ThroughModel"`?

Comment: right , Django so specified https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships and working in admin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use through Model for this.
Basically Django create only intermediate table in db, not model. So you need to define Model class to register it in the Admin.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

Comment: Too bad, i was hoping to avoid the through model. Thanks!

Comment: @ÖzerS. You can define model class for already existing table. Create `ParentChild` model pass it as `through` kwarg, create migration and then fake it. It might be a bit tricky - but in the end you will get consistent migrations and don't lose your data.